# Windows Phone 8.1 receive SMS event

Tags: c#, sms, windows-phone-8.1

My simple program must be working in the background and react to an event receiving SMS. Can it be done on this platform? I did not find any useful information before.

Answer (score 2):

There is something called [SmsReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn408658.aspx) trigger but I think it's only for operator apps.

So unless you work on an app for a mobile operator, it's not possible.

Comment: maybe, exist an event that responsive to any type notifications (SMS, Email, Twitter)?